# Webapp map static resources to jar in Tomcat

Tags: java, html, tomcat, web-applications, war

I am porting a web app to tomcat and I have a problem with static resources.

I have a jar that contains the web resources (css, img, js, ... files). These files are packaged in a path resembling this:

```
data.jar
com/bizname/application/web/css
com/bizname/application/web/img
com/bizname/application/web/js
```

The jar is inside the web application. I want to be able to map the resources to public acces. For example if I acces :

```
http://myserver:8080/mywebapp/css/style.css
```

I want the resource `com/bizname/application/web/css/style.css` to be delivered.

I cant find how to set up this in the `web.xml`-file of Tomcat.

In Jetty embedded, I was able to use handles to achieve this.

```
final URL url_css = Servidor.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/bizname/application/web/css");
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.addHandler(new WebAppContext(url_css.toExternalForm(),"/css"));
// ... adding handler to context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [jawr](https://jawr.java.net/index.html) can help you.

If not, you can implement a Servlet that does it for you (reading the file and writing it to the response). If you use something like Resteasy it will be easier because you don't need to write the IO stuff.

Comment: I implemented a servlet to handle static data delivery.

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure this is right, considering I have only worked with Tomcat from Eclipse, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

I am assuming you are using Java Servlets in this app? If that is the case, then you need to specify the URL-patterns in web.xml. Here is a great example of a web.xml file from apache.org which explains the aspects of the file:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/appdev/web.xml.txt

Hope this helps you!